# What is the term for "possible breakage points" or "waists" in a non-convex 3D solid?

Tags: terminology, maxima-minima, solid-geometry

Consider a three-dimensional solid such as the Prince Rupert's Cube in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3-Ta9DF4Cg). This solid has some narrow places where it could easily break.

Now, *any* solid (even a solid cube) has narrow places (e.g., at the corners of the cube), but we don't consider those breakage risks, and I think the reason is that they're convex. The interesting thing about the narrow "wasp waists" in the 3D-printed artifact above is that they're non-convex. In the language of [Maehara & Tokushige (2008)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f673/e85125df6ebe3becb3c573019f9ac29dc833.pdf), the solid can be "held" by a "frame" around one of these waists.

I'm looking for mathematical terminology to describe either:

- What do we call the "waist" points where the area of the smallest "cut" through the solid hits a local minimum?
- What do we call the area of that "cut" itself? It strikes me as similar but not the same as *diameter* in solid geometry. It also strikes me as analogous to *minimum cut* in graph theory, but I can't really articulate why.
- Is there any sense in asking for the "minimum cut" through a nonconvex solid's waists that separates it into two or more pieces? If so, is there a name for that?

Comment: These are interesting geometric ideas. I don't think they have established names, so invent your own. "Waist" is a good place to start.